# The usage that I wish to clarify

Tags: word-usage

In the quoted speech,

> Laurel said, "I would be much obliged if you are to send ..."

Would it be okay if a person uses "you're to"?

and,
how do you differentiate the usage of the following words

> Alone, Lone, Lonesome, Loneliness, Aloneness, Lonely, Alonely [I suppose]

> Lay, Lie, Laid, Lain

> Fill up the form, Fill in the form, Fill out the form

if you could answer them separately, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: You should ask each question separately. Stack exchange works best with a single question per thread. Also you should include your research (which dictionaries you've consulted, etc.) for each question.

Comment: After *I would be*, I'd expect something happening in the future, when that appreciation shows, not *you are* or *you're*. And when you look up *lone* and *alone*, notice being by yourself but not sad.

Comment: Zero hits in a Google online search for "obliged if you are to". I'd say this is ungrammatical, so how can converting to a contracted form make things 'okay'?  Other questions are largely general reference or a duplicate.